# Multiprocessing error: AssertionError: cannot start a process twice

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Let's say that the function update_values have some firebase commands which take about 2 secs to execute but I don't want to stop my camera and wait for that. So I used multiprocessing, so that the camera doesn't stop and the code still updates the value, but I'm facing this issue.
 `AssertionError: cannot start a process twice`
How should I resolve this?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from firebase import firebase
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseApplication
import multiprocessing

def update_values():
    x=np.random.randint(100)
    print("Updating Values") 
    print("done")

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)


#for improving fps
flag=0
#establishing connnection with the database for the first time
firebase_message = firebase.FirebaseApplication("<link to database>", None)    #reconnecting to the existing table
print("Connectionion Established")

t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=update_values)

count_down=0
count_up=0
while(cap.isOpened()):
    _,frame=cap.read()
    x=np.random.randint(100)
    if(flag%100==0):
            t1.start()
    flag+=1
    cv2.imshow('frame',result)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if k == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Your t1.start() is a part of an If block, which is also a part of the while block. So, it is possible that t1.start() will be called many times, including these occasions where it's already running. Change if(flag%100==0) to if (flag%100==0) and t1.is_Alive() == False: - this should prevent t1.start() from executing if t1 is already running.

Comment: ... or move `t1 = multiprocessing...` to the suite of that if statement and create a new process each time.

Comment: okay..that makes sense..I tried threading and did what @wwii said...I put `t1 = multiprocessing` inside of if and it works...Its working and I suppose there shouldn't be a problem..

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Hello, @wwii, I just posted my answer at the bottom, please do check..

Answer (score 0):

which operating system? On Windows, multiprocessing calls must be protected by `if __name__=='__main__':` to prevent infinite process creation

[Python - Multiprocessing Error 'cannot start a process twice'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386006/python-multiprocessing-error-cannot-start-a-process-twice)

Comment: I'm using windows...and I tried threading to solve my problem...I will share the solution as an answer..just point out if there are any errors..

Answer (score 0):

So, I switched to threading and I'm making new threads every time it enters the if condition...here is the code...

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from firebase import firebase
from firebase.firebase import FirebaseApplication
import threading

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#for improving fps
flag=0
#establishing connnection with the database for the first time
firebase_message = firebase.FirebaseApplication("<link to database>", None)    #reconnecting to the existing table
print("Connectionion Established")

def update_values():
    x=np.random.randint(100)
    print("Updating Values")
    print("done")



count_down=0
count_up=0
while(cap.isOpened()):
    _,frame=cap.read()
    
    x=np.random.randint(100)
    
    if(flag%100==0):
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=update_values)    
            t1.start()
            print("Done")
    flag+=1
    cv2.imshow('frame',result)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if k == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: if anything is off about this code then please do comment..